# How to create own dataset for using Mask-RCNN models from the Tensorflow Object Detection API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, mask, object-detection, object-detection-api

I do not quite understand this guide:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/instance_segmentation.md

I have many objects of three classes. According to the guide I have to make mask with dimension [N, H, W], where:

- N - count of objects
- H - image height
- W - image width

I have this function to create a mask

```
def image_mask(img, polygons):
    w, h = img.size
    n = len(polygons)
    mask = np.zeros([n, h, w], dtype=np.float32)
    for i in range(0, n):
        polygon = polygons[i].reshape((-1, 1, 2))
        tmp_mask = np.zeros([h, w], dtype=np.float32)
        cv2.fillPoly(tmp_mask, [polygon], (1, 1, 1))
        mask[i, :, :] = tmp_mask
    return mask
```

I use this guide for creating my dataset:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md

I add a mask to the end of tf_example

```
tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
...
      'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
      'image/object/mask': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(mask.reshape((-1))),
  }))
```

Because of `reshape` (I suppose), RAM quickly runs out and I get a memory error. What am I doing wrong? Maybe somewhere there is a detailed guide, how to create a mask for using Mask-RCNN and Tensorflow Object Detection API? I did not find this.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but it looks like you aren't converting your mask data to bytes before sending it to a bytes_list_feature.

If there are still memory issues, the `'image/object/mask'` feature can be a list of bytes strings, one for each object. If you have a very large `n`, the other option (a `NxHxW` array that must be manipulated after compilation) may cause memory issues.

Here's how to compile an instance map data into object masks using the bytes list option:

```py
# a HxW array of integer instance IDs, one per each unique object
inst_map_data = func_to_get_inst_map_data(inst_map_path)
                    
object_masks = []
class_labels = []
for inst_id in np.unique(inst_map_data): # loop through all objects

    # a HxW array of 0's and 1's, 1's representing where this object is
    obj_mask_data = np.where(inst_map_data==inst_id, 1, 0)
                
    # encode as png for space saving
    is_success, buffer = cv2.imencode(".png", obj_mask_data)
    io_buf = io.BytesIO(buffer)

    # a bytes string
    obj_mask_data_bytes = io_buf.getvalue()
                        
    object_masks += [obj_mask_data_bytes]
    class_labels += [int((inst_id-inst_id%1000)/1000)]

tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
...
      'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(class_labels),
      'image/object/mask': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(object_masks),
  }))
```